# Ambiguity on EF.Functions Using EF Core 7

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I've just updated my project to .NET 7 and EF Core 7, I'm getting the following error when compiling:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlDbFunctionsExtensions.DateDiffDay and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions.DateDiffDay

The offending lines uses the EF.Functions extensions to execute SQL datetime comparisons

```
query = query.Where(x => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(DateA, DateB) >= DateToTest);
```

Any pointers on how to solve this?

Here's the list of my nuget packages from the `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup" Version="3.7.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.7.300" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SQS" Version="3.7.300" />
    <PackageReference Include="CoreFtp" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="30.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="11.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin" Version="0.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="8.0.0-rc.2.23480.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="7.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.13">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="110.2.1-alpha.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="LinqKit.Core" Version="1.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.8.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="itext7" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="7.0.2-dev-00546" />
    <PackageReference Include="serilog.sinks.graylog" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SSH.NET" Version="2023.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="6.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Do you have both MySQL and SQL Server EF packages installed?

Comment: Just SQLServer ones, hence the strangeness of this error

Comment: Can you [edit] your post with the listing of nuget packages in your csproj file?

Comment: @gunr2171 Added the information you requested

Comment: Pretty sure that the official `MySqlDbFunctionsExtensions` is in namespace MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions. But Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql places their extension in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Which may be exposed through one of your dependencies?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman this was exactly the issue, had to alias the pomelo lib, issue solved!

Comment: But why do you have Pomelo installed in the first place?

Comment: @Charlieface That's the catch, i did not have it installed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the pomelo lib (that ***wasn't*** referenced in my nuget packages, hence the weirdness of this error...) was getting in the way of ef core server functions, i've solved the problem with an aliased include

```
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="7.0.0">
            <Aliases>PomeloMySql</Aliases>
        </PackageReference>
```

Comment: btw, OOT, you able to run MySQL with EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin?

Comment: Hey Raden, i wasn't running mysql, the database i'm using is SQL SERVER, had this weird issue with PomeloMySql but i'm not using it.